# NSData contentsOfUrl returning nil

Tags: swift, nsdata

Im trying to simply get a jpeg image from an url but when using NSData with contentsOfUrl is returning nil.

```
let aString = "http://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/t31.0-8/q88/s720x720/10848858_907722502601079_2834541930671169073_o.jpg"
let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: aString)
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to load a remote file with [`fileURLWithPath`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURL/fileURLWithPath:) which points to a system path.

What you are trying to achieve, can be done like this:

```
let aString = "http://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/t31.0-8/q88/s720x720/10848858_907722502601079_2834541930671169073_o.jpg"
let url = NSURL(string: aString)
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
```